# Why does setting a variable equal to setTimeout function immediately run it?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert('Hello, Mr. Universe!');
  }, 2000)
```

This runs immediately, and outputs the alert after 2 seconds (at least) depending on the stack.
But I'm wondering why the following also behaves this way.

```
  let myGreeting = setTimeout(function() {
    alert('Hello, Mr. Universe!');
  }, 2000)
```

Isn't this just a function expression? Why does it run even without an invocation, i.e., myGreeting()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To initiate the timeout by making a function call, do the setTimeout in body of the function, rather than assigning it...

```
// not const myGreeting = setTimeout, but...
const myGreeting = () => {
  return setTimeout(() => {
    alert('Hello, Mr. Universe!');
  }, 2000);
}

// call it
const timeoutId = myGreeting() // after 2 seconds, 'Hello..."
```

Comment: Got it, is there any reason to do one over the other?

Comment: @ILikeThePoopSmith, coding it as in the OP will immediately initiate the timeout and give you the id to clear it with.  The function I suggest does the same, but initiates only after you call it.

Comment: I still don't quite understand why the OP's version with myGreeting executes immediately? Is it because it has to execute to resolve the assignment?

Comment: Yes, @ILikeThePoopSmith, exactly.  Consider `let num = Math.abs(-3)`.  What will num be after that statement is executed?

Answer (score 1):

[`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) returns an id to use with [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout). In your first example, you are just ignoring the return value, so the result should not differ.

Comment: Wait but when I assign the variable myGreeting to setTimeout, why does it run even if I don't invoke it?

Comment: @ILikeThePoopSmith You are setting the variable `myGreeting` to the return value of `setTimeout`, which is a timeout id. You're calling the `setTimeout` function regardless.

Comment: *why does it run even if I don't invoke it* You are clearly invoking `setTimeout` and assigning whatever it returns to `myGreeting`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are confused as to the semantics of `let`.  The right hand expression of the equal sign here is still getting evaluated at the time of assignment. You are not "setting `myGreeting` to *some expression*.  You are setting `myGreeting` to the *result of evaluating some expression*.

Answer (score -1):

??? Oki let’s take whatever setTimeout has inside `setTimeout()` you is calling it that’s why it runs